# Как добавить сумму элементов из двух массивов в третий? Внутри объекта

Tags: javascript

> Почему значения элементов в массиве finalPay имеют значение NAN? Как добавить сумму элементов массивов billValues и allTips в массив finalPay?

```
var restaurantPays = {
billValues : [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
allTips : [],
finalPay : [],
tipCalculator : function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++) {
        var percentage;
        if (this.billValues[i] < 50) {
            percentage = .2;
        } else if (this.billValues[i] >= 50 && this.billValues[i] < 200) {
            percentage = .15;
        } else {
            percentage = .1;
        } 
        this.allTips[i] = this.billValues[i] * percentage;
    }
},
finalPayCalc : function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.billValues.length; i++) {
        this.finalPay[i] = this.billValues[i] + this.allTips[i];
    }
}
}

 restaurantPays.finalPayCalc();
 restaurantPays.tipCalculator();

 console.log(restaurantPays);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок вызова функций у тебя некорректный ( то есть ты сначала вызываешь функцию  finalPayCalc(), в логике которой ты используешь переменные, которые заполняешь в функции в tipCalculator() )

```
 restaurantPays.tipCalculator();
 restaurantPays.finalPayCalc();
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Кстати, я потом добавил "this.finalPay[i] = this.billValues[i] + this.allTips[i];" в первый цикл, тоже помогло.